# Passing arguments to parent controller method in nested recursive directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, callback, angular-directive

I'm struggling to call a parent controller function in a nested directive that recursively compiles itself. Clicking on the button in `tree-item` works one level deep, but after that the variables for `doc` and `type` are undefined.

This type of issue is trivially resolved with React, but I think new scopes are being created with every function pass, when really I just want to pass the callback reference from the parent.

I think this could be solved by emitting events, is this a bad / good idea?

Parent controller method:

```
displayDocument(doc, type) { /* */ }
```

Passed down to `tree` directive:

```
<tree display-document="vm.displayDocument(doc, type)"></tree>
```

`Tree` definition:

```
function Tree() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'components/ui/biospecimen/templates/tree.html',
    scope: {
      displayDocument: '&',
    }
  }
}
```

Passed to `tree-item` directive from `tree.html`:

```
<tree-item display-document="displayDocument(doc, type)"></tree-item>
```

`TreeItem` definition:

```
function TreeItem($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'components/ui/biospecimen/templates/tree-item.html',
    scope: {
      displayDocument: '&',
    },
    link: (scope, el, attrs) => {
      el.append($compile([
        '<tree',        
          'data-ng-repeat="childType in [\'foo\', \'bar\']"',
          'display-document="displayDocument(doc, type)"',
        '></tree>'
      ].join(' '))(scope))
    }
  }
}
```

And then finally used inside `tree-item`:

```
<button data-ng-click="displayDocument({ doc: doc, type: type })">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your almost there. Your problem is that when you invoke a function from a directive, you must pass it an object, just like you did when you pass the object from tree item to tree. Angular then invoke the function in the tree directive like so:

```
displayDocument(doc, type)
```

the problem is that this function is also inside a directive!, it must be invoked in the same way, like this:

```
displayDocument({ doc: doc, type: type })
```

So if the function in the tree directive must be invoked with **one** argument (that is the object { doc: doc, type: type }) then when you invoke it from the tree item, you must write it in the template like so:

```
<tree-item display-document="displayDocument(args)"></tree-item>
```

(or any other name instead of 'args')
and invoke it like so:

```
<button data-ng-click="displayDocument({args: { doc: doc, type: type }})">Click</button>
```

I created a working [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8hamd5m/) the resembles your situation